# Is it okay to store database creds in Angular files for production apps?

Tags: security, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm beginning to build an Angular 2 app with Firebase, hosted with Firebase, and I need to store my credentials.

When the app is running in production will it be safe to store my database credentials in my app.module.ts file?

Comment: Only if you want to make it publicly available.

Comment: If I need to use an api key to call the database, where do I store that?

Comment: *12 factor apps* store credentials in the environment.

Comment: You can store the API key in the source code. The API key should be limited to a specific referrer (in the API console) so it can only be used when the application is loaded from where you deploy it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482366/is-it-safe-to-expose-firebase-apikey-to-the-public

Comment: @Paul: as the answer Gunter linked says, the important thing to realize is that your API (like the other config parameters) are **not** credentials. They are just identifiers that the app needs to find its project on the Firebase servers.